# UITextField and UIDatePicker reusable code

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

Hi found this code here on reddit which change the keyboard of a textfield into `UIDatepicker` so we can select date. The code works great. However, I'm trying to refactor this make it reusable since I have 3 textfields on the same VC that all need to be able to select the date. Here is the code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var txtDatePicker: UITextField!
    let datePicker = UIDatePicker()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        showDatePicker()
    }


    func showDatePicker(){
        //Formate Date
        datePicker.datePickerMode = .date

        //ToolBar
        let toolbar = UIToolbar();
        toolbar.sizeToFit()
        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(donedatePicker));
        let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(cancelDatePicker));

        toolbar.setItems([doneButton,spaceButton,cancelButton], animated: false)

        txtDatePicker.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
        txtDatePicker.inputView = datePicker

    }

    @objc func donedatePicker(){

        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
        txtDatePicker.text = formatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    @objc func cancelDatePicker(){
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

Here is what I have tried but I'm having problems with passing argument through the #selector

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var txtDatePicker: UITextField!
    let datePicker = UIDatePicker()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        showDatePicker(textField: txtDatePicker)
    }


    func showDatePicker(textField: UITextField){
        //Formate Date
        datePicker.datePickerMode = .date

        //ToolBar
        let toolbar = UIToolbar();
        toolbar.sizeToFit()
        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(donedatePicker(textField:)));
        let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(cancelDatePicker));

        toolbar.setItems([doneButton,spaceButton,cancelButton], animated: false)

        textField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
        textField.inputView = datePicker

    }

    @objc func donedatePicker(textField: UITextField){

        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
        textField.text = formatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    @objc func cancelDatePicker(){
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you use a **custom** `UITextField` for this case.

```
class CustomTextField: UITextField {

    lazy var datePicker: UIDatePicker = {
        let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
        datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
        return datePicker
    }()

    lazy var toolBar: UIToolbar = {
        let toolbar = UIToolbar()
        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(donedatePicker))
        let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(cancelDatePicker))

        toolbar.setItems([doneButton,spaceButton,cancelButton], animated: false)
        toolbar.sizeToFit()
        return toolbar
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        addDatePicker()
    }

    func addDatePicker() {
        inputAccessoryView = toolBar
        inputView = datePicker
    }

    @objc func donedatePicker(){
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
        text = formatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
        endEditing(true)
    }

    @objc func cancelDatePicker() {
        endEditing(true)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

---

**Note:** I have not checked your code. I have just refactored in the best way possible for a custom class.

Comment: Hi I added this to my project and set the UITextField with this class but when I run the app I get the "init(coder:) has not been implemented" am I applying it wrong?

Comment: @MightAsWell you missed the last method in my answer.

Comment: I copy and paste the whole thing into a swift file do I have to initiate anything in my viewcontroller file?

Comment: @MightAsWell If you click on the red warning, it will show a suggestion which will fix the issue. You need to create textfields with this class whenever you need one with datepicker and toolbar.

Comment: @MightAsWell Use  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}